# jboss application redirect to another port

Tags: java, redirect, web-applications, jboss, proxy

We have an environment with multiple JBoss 5.1 GA server instances running on different ports (8080,8180 etc).

I've got a web application deployed to a server instance which I want to access from one of the another server instances. Is this possible and if it is then what is the best practice for achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to access it?

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Something preventing you from doing a GET to http://localhost:8180 ? Or do you want to redirect there.